# how to access outside selector in this example

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div class='header-vals' data-item-id='23'>
  <input type='text' name='some-input' />
  <input type='text' name='some-other-input' />
</div>
```

and would like ot access the data-item-id with something like this (but this doesn't work):

```
$('.header-vals').on('keyup','input',function(){
  var item_id=$(this).data('item-id');
});
```

Is there a way to make the reference of this to the outside so that I can get the data-item-id?

thx in advance

Comment: I think you're looking for the [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function -- e.g. `$(this).attr('data-item-id')`.

Comment: Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the input element, which does not have a `data-item-id` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
$('.header-vals').on('keyup','input',function(){
  alert($(this).parent().attr('data-item-id'));
});​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/79dEd/)**

Comment: `.data()` just works fine... anyway, +1 for providing a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item_id = $(this).parent().attr('data-item-id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Felix is correct (and thanks buddy)..

$(this) is referring to the input... check the code below, just add parent:

Your code will work, just switch data with attr

```
$('.header-vals').on('keyup','input',function(){
  var item_id=$(this).parent.attr('data-item-id');
});
```

the .data() function is used for binding data to an element, not selecting attributes
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: jQuery automatically adds `data-` attributes to the internal `.data` storage. This is equivalent to the OPs code. The problem is that the input element does not have a `data-item-id` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.header-vals').on('keyup','input',function(){ 
  var item_id=$(this).parent().attr('data-item-id'); 
});
```

OR

```
$('.header-vals').on('keyup','input',function(){ 
  var item_id=$(this).parent().data('item-id'); 
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79dEd/1/) with using the data function.

Comment: jQuery automatically adds `data-` attributes to the internal `.data` storage. This is equivalent to the OPs code. The problem is that the input element does not have a `data-item-id` attribute.