# syntax for creating event handlers on html that is added after document load

Tags: jquery

I am adding some html to the DOM after the document has loaded via jQuery (and a follow-up to this but not that relavant [how to access outside selector in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868876/how-to-access-outside-selector-in-this-example)). I would like to bind a 'keyup' to input elements that are wrapped in class '.item-vals'. My understanding is that the first syntax should limit the testing by jQuery for that event to only elements that exist in the class '.item-vals'. Since '.item-vals' would be more specific, I think it would perform better than using document.  Is there a way to make the second syntax work?

```
// doesn't work
$('.item-vals').on('keyup','input',function(){

// does work
$(document).on('keyup','.item-vals input',function(){
```

thx in advance (and sorry for all jQuery questions)

Comment: Do the elements with class `item-vals` exit when you bind the event hander (`$('.item-vals').on(...)`)? If not, it won't work. You have to bind the event handler to the closest elements that **exist**: *"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`.*" - http://api.jquery.com/on/ (it's printed in bold!).

Comment: You should delegate the event from one of static parents of the element.

Comment: You should be able to make `$('body').on('keyup','.item-vals input',function(){ ... });` work

Comment: hmm... really? I swear I could do this with .live?

Comment: ok @TiesonT.  that's why document is working, just concerned with performance if form grows

Comment: @timpone `live` works because it delegates the event from document object.

Comment: y, not using it. honestly, do jQuery / javascript like 10% of time. appreciate all the help

Comment: @timpone Yeah, `body` is a terrible selector; I just threw one in there that works without knowing your markup. The idea is to use the closest container that won't change, as Todd Horst shows below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.live` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Instead of `document` use a container div so that the event doesn`t have to bubble to the top.

```
$('#MyContainerThatExistsOnPageLoad').on('keyup','.item-vals input',function(){
```